# Alternative for exists query

Tags: sql

I have the following query :

```
update tab1.abc,
tab1.sbd = (select tab2.abc, tab2.sbd from tab2,tab1 where --some conditions)
where exists(select tab2.abc, tab2.sbd from tab2,tab1 where --some conditions)
```

Now my task is to optmize this query.

I believe removing the exists clause or combining both the where clauses would help a lot.
But how to do it ?

**PS** : exists clause is in place because I want the number of rows updated to be zero if the select clause returns zero rows.

Comment: Please include the exact query.  By filtering out the `--some conditions` we can't actually see what your query does and how to refactor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables instead of `EXISTS`. Something like the following:

```
UPDATE tab1
INNER JOIN tab2 ON --some join condition
SET sbd = --something
AND abc = --other something
WHERE --some conditions
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I fetch the data for update from three tables and make a check on some parameters of each of these tables, Wouldnt a join become very costly in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use IN keyword

```
update tab1.abc,
tab1.sbd = (select tab2.abc, tab2.sbd from tab2,tab1 where --some  conditions)
where something in 
(select tab2.abc, tab2.sbd from tab2,tab1 where --some conditions)
```

refer below links:

[IN (TSql)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

[SQL IN](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlin.html)

Comment: I dont think this would better the performance, as we are runnng the same query twice?